# ffmpeg slideshow on raspberry pi raspbian

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, jpeg, slideshow

i'm trying to make slideshow video from few (in this case 3) .jpgs. To do this i'm using

```
    ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i bat%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p proba12.mp4
```

and actually it works on windows (it plays every image for 5seconds) but on raspbian it doesnt work neither on omxplayer nor hello_video.bin (in h264).

Here is what console shows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i bat%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p proba12.mp4
ffmpeg version N-89047-g54f8ac199f Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 20170516
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  3.101 / 58.  3.101
  libavformat    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.101 /  7.  0.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'bat%03d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080             
[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x31ac620] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec     - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r               ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fa               st_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3                b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree               =1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'proba12.mp4':
  Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf58.2.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc58.3.101 libx264
Side data:
  cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  449 fps=8.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1341kB time=00:00:14.86 bitrate= 738.9kbits/s dup=446 drop=0 speed=0.265x
video:1335kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.457740%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame I:3     Avg QP:15.58  size:442255
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame P:113   Avg QP:18.36  size:   130
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] frame B:333   Avg QP:27.00  size:    74
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  0.0%  0.0% 98.9%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb I  I16..4:  2.0% 94.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.6%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:19.2% L1:80.8% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] 8x8 transform intra:94.5% inter:61.3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 85.4% 31.7% 25.4% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 20%  9% 29%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 11% 33%  5%  7%  6%  8%  5%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 14% 15%  7% 11%  8%  9%  9%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 82%  8%  7%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref P L0: 99.5%  0.0%  0.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref B L0: 71.2% 28.6%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] ref B L1: 99.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x30fef00] kb/s:730.29
```

what is also strange if im trying to concatenate those files using text file and i set duration to 5 for every single file it makes different display time... in this example first one displays for 15 seconds, second one for 5seconds and the last one for 10seconds... of course this way of merging images doesnt work under raspbian either

i'm using raspberry pi 3b with latest raspbian noobs on board

can you guys please direct me on a solution? im ran out of ideas... cheers